# Setting memLimitMB parameter in Mongodb for memory limit

Tags: mongodb

I am using **Mongodb version 3.6.13** using docker-compose file.I want to limit the memory consumption for mongodb as monogdb utilises all the available memory of OS. In the documents i found **"memLimitMB"** parameter, reference "https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/command/hostInfo/". When i execute the query "db.hostInfo()" inside mongo container it gives

```
system" : {
                "currentTime" : ISODate("2020-04-28T11:47:58.179Z"),
                "hostname" : "xyz",
                "cpuAddrSize" : 64,
                "memSizeMB" : 7823,
                "memLimitMB" : 7823,
                "numCores" : 4,
                "cpuArch" : "x86_64",
                "numaEnabled" : false
        },
```

and some other information related to OS.

I want to change **memLimitMB** parameter value to my desired value as per my memory constraints. Is their any environment variable available or some configuration through which i can change the value of this parameter to my desired value.

Comment: Hi @Yatin, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this needs to be set on Docker level, not on MongoDB level. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) for documentation.